# Convert an array of ids in JSON into an array of POJOs in Java with Spring

Tags: java, json, spring

Let's say I have a POJO like that:

```
class SomePOJO {
    List<SomeEntity> entities;

    ...
}
```

And a JSON structure like this:

```
{
    "entities" : [1, 5, 10, 15]
}
```

In the JSON structure, the "entities" array is just an array of IDs. With a framework like Jackson, is it possible to seamlessly construct an object of type `SomePOJO` from the mentioned JSON structure, converting ids to `SomeEntity` objects in the process using, for example, a Spring Data Repository.

I can't really use a static method here because I need to refer to some kind of a bean - a repository, to get a full object from an id.

I know this is not impossible, but what are some "nice-looking" solutions? Something like `@JsonCreator`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at the answers for this other question: [Customize jackson unmarshalling behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208087/customize-jackson-unmarshalling-behavior)

Just combine those with Spring's dependency injection, and you should be good to go.